# how to find column value based on multiple conditions in excel?

Tags: excel, multiple-conditions

I need help with Excel.
My data frame looks like this:

```
TABLE1  
ID DateFrom    DateTo      Parameter  
ab1 2017-01-01  2017-01-03  A  
ac1 2017-01-05  2017-01-07  A  
ab1 2017-01-06  2017-01-08  B  

TABLE2  
ID Date   
ac1 2017-01-06   
ab1 2017-01-08  
ab1 2017-01-01
```

I need to make a 3rd column in TABLE2 with a Parameter value from TABLE1 based on TABLE2 ID and Date. It should look like this:

```
ID Date Parameter  
ac1 2017-01-06 A  
ab1 2017-01-08 B  
ab1 2017-01-01 A
```

I was thinking about VLOOKUP, IF, INDEX/MATCH formulas. It should probably be a combination of these, but I cannnot make it work.....

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2010 or later use this formula:

```
=INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($D$2:$D$4)/((F2=$A$2:$A$4)*(G2>=$B$2:$B$4)*(G2<=$C$2:$C$4)),1))
```

If you have 2007 or older use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$4,MATCH(1,(F2=$A$2:$A$4)*(G2>=$B$2:$B$4)*(G2<=$C$2:$C$4),0))
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]